# how can I combine two search code into one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input fields with drop-downs to each. What I am doing is on clicking of drop-down I have an input field inside it which is working as the search for that field.

So for both of the dropdowns to search, I have to write a separate search code for that. what I am trying to achieve is:

1. I want to write only one search code which will search for all dropdown
2. simply I want to minimize my code

**Code Snippet**

```js
$.ajax({ //this one is to populate categorycode dropdwon

  url: 'CategoryCode',
  method: 'GET',
  success: function(categoryCodeData) {
    let dropdown = $('#itemCodeDropdown');
    dropdown.empty();
    dropdown.append('<input type="text" class="form-control" id="categorySearch" placeholder="search">');
    $.each(categoryCodeData, function(key, entry) {
      dropdown.append($('<a class="dropdown-item"></a>').attr('value', entry.name).text(entry.code).click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".input-group").find("input").val($(this).text())
      }))

    });

  },
  'error': function(err) {}
})
$.ajax({
  url: 'myurl',
  method: 'GET',
  success: function(itemCodeData) {
    let dropdown = $('#itemCodeDropdown');
    dropdown.empty();
    dropdown.append('<input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemSearch" placeholder="search">');
    $.each(itemCodeData, function(key, entry) {
      dropdown.append($('<a class="dropdown-item"></a>').attr('value', entry.name).text(entry.code).click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".input-group").find("input").val($(this).text())
      }))

    });

  },
  'error': function(err) {}
})

$("#itemCodeSearch").on("keyup", function() { //this is the search code i am writing for item code i have to write for category code also but with minimization of code
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $("#itemCodeDropdown a").filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
      });
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <label for="itemCode">Item Code</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" id="itemCodeInput">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="itemCodeDropdown"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <label for="brandCode">Category Code</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" id="brandCodeInput">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="categoryCodeDropdown">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I have written a code to search for `item-code` ,I have commented on the line where i am writing that code in my snippet.

Now to have searched for `category code` I have to write a new code for that
So I want to minimize my code so that I can write only one search code and it work for all dropdowns according to their `id` I have define

**Note** In my real code I have more then 10 `input fields` with drop-down here I am using only 2

**itemCodeData**

```
[{"code":"1234","name":"banana"},{"code":"6962","name":"rice"},{"code":"5965","name":"icecream"},{"code":"5678","name":"cake"},{"code":"5678","name":"apple"},{"code":"9635","name":"grapes"}]
```

**categoryCodeData**

```
[{"code":"C001","name":"Beverages"},{"code":"C002","name":"Juices"},{"code":"C003","name":"Cookies"},{"code":"C004","name":"Breads"},{"code":"C005","name":"Biscuits"},{"code":"C006","name":"Savouries"}]
```

Comment: Write a function with two parameter one is element and other searchcode and use for both input elements. So it reduced to single search function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add your input as entries in an array containing `($dropdown, dropdownId, dropdownData)` tuples and then loop over it:

```
// Add as many entries as you wish in this array
[
  ['#itemCodeDropdown', 'itemCodeSearch', 'itemUrl'],
  ['#categoryCodeDropdown', 'categorySearch', 'categoryUrl'],
].forEach(([selector, searchId, endpointUrl]) => {
  // ...
}
```

Demo using dummy endpoint URLs:

```js
[
  ['#itemCodeDropdown', 'itemCodeSearch', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'],
  ['#categoryCodeDropdown', 'categorySearch', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums'],
].forEach(([selector, searchId, endpointUrl]) => {
  $.ajax({
    url: endpointUrl,
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      const dropdown = $(selector);
      dropdown.empty();
      dropdown.append('<input type="text" class="form-control" id="' + searchId + '" placeholder="search">');
      
      $.each(data, function(key, entry) {
        dropdown.append($('<a class="dropdown-item"></a>').attr('value', entry.id).text(entry.title).on('click', function() {
          $(this).closest('.input-group').find('input').val($(this).text())
        }));
      });

      $('#' + searchId).on('keyup', function() {
        const value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $(selector + ' a').filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      });
    },
    'error': function(err) {}
  })
});
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <label for="itemCode">Item Code</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" id="itemCodeInput">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="itemCodeDropdown"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <label for="brandCode">Category Code</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" id="brandCodeInput">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="categoryCodeDropdown">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @manishthakur How so? If you run code snippet from the answer it seems to be doing fine. What isn't what it should be?

Comment: look it is not searching category code.. i have to work on search code not on the code which is populating dropdown..you have looped my dropdown populating code

Comment: @manishthakur Edited my answer, forgot the dropdown IDs. Better now?

Comment: @manishthakur Indeed forgot the filtering, now should be all fine. Check the editer answer and let me know.

Comment: I am using ajax to get data fro server and the data variable is inside the success function for each dropdown i am making ajax call, so how can i use `itemcodedata` outside that success funtion?

Comment: @manishthakur Not sure to follow, can you the corresponding code? Maybe edit your question with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188337/discussion-between-manish-thakur-and-jeto).

Comment: @manishthakur I've updated the answer using `$.ajax` calls. Now hopefully that solves your actual issue :) Just replace with your actual URLs and `entry.name` / `entry.code` instead of `entry.title` / `entry.id` in the callback function.